# Requisição get Falhando

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-request, axios

Olá, estou com um problema que está afetando meu desenvolvimento. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que utilizo Axios e Vue.js e Desejo fazer um primeiro get em um dado que irá para uma props e nisso ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei fazer várias outras formas e todas cai neste mesmo erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a imagem do código.
Como faço para solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa resolver a promise antes de poder utilizar o valor. Segue um exemplo:

```
 async asyncData (context) {
    try {
        const { data } = await context.$axios.$get('/vagas')
        return { vagas: data, errorMessage: '' }
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.response.status === 404 || e.response.status === 400 || e.response.status === 500) {
            const { data } = e.response;
            return { vagas: [], errorMessage: data.errors[0].msg }
        } else if (e.request) {
            return { vagas: [], errorMessage: e.request }
        }
        return { vagas: [], errorMessage: e.message }
    }
}
```

Caso seja necessário posso adicionar mais trechos do código.

Caso não seja possível utilizar o padrão `async/await`. Pode-se utilizar o .then e .catch. Segue um exemplo.

```
axios.post('/formulas/create', {
    name: "",
    parts: ""
})
.then(response => { 
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu já consegui resolver de outra forma.
```
async created() {
    await this.axios("http://localhost:8000/items")
      .then((response) => (this.items = response.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  },
```